# Google LAMP stack final install steps

Tags: google-compute-engine

After I launched a new LAMP stack VM, I was given some final steps to complete (secure php/sql, etc). Unfortunately, my laptop crashed before I could finish. I've tried find those final steps, to no avail. Anyone have a link to those steps, or point me to something similar? I'm afraid I haven't done this enough times to remember, and it's my first go with Google cloud. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What did you use to launch the LAMP stack VM? Did you launch it through the market place? Is it currently running? We need some more information to help.

Comment: Good questions: yes, to both. Launched from marketplace and it is currently running.

Comment: Another question I have relates to super user access,etc. I see that I have a user account created from my gmail account (auto generated as part of my login I assume). But what about super user access? I assume as the owner, I'm guessing my user has root level access. But if I need to switch to super user to do something, what password am I entering? My gmail password. I feel like I missed these details somewhere. If there is a guide with all the best practices, etc and covers these items, please point me in the right direction. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can just delete the the current VM and launch a new one. From there, you can complete the installation steps. To answer your other question, you will automatically have root access, you do not need to enter a password for root access.